# Center a new Form inside of a Parent form and Block until input and received.

Tags: c#, forms, user-interface

I'm working with a form written in C#.  I want to prompt for input in a little pop-up form.  I want the pop-up to be centered in the original form.

I tried doing something like this:

```
pop_up.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
pop_up.MdiParent = this;
pop_up.ShowDialog();
```

But, I get an exception saying: "Form that is not a top-level form cannot be displayed as a modal dialog box. Remove the form from any parent form before calling showDialog."

If I call `show()` instead of `showDialog()` then the program doesn't wait until input is entered before continuing, which is what I want to happen.  If I don't set the parent, then the pop-up isn't centered and gets rendered in different places depending on what window is focused.

So, how can I do this?  How do I get my pop-up to be tied to the parent form and still block the parent form until the pop-up closes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is simply possible by changing your code to the following:

```
  pop_up.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
  pop_up.ShowDialog(this);
```

The parameter we are passing will make the dialog's parent be the form that is calling this code.

Comment: Looks like being 3 seconds late worked out this time! :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
using (var form = new Form())
{
    form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
    form.ShowDialog(this);

    // access the form values here
} // now the form is released.
```

Comment: Wow 3 seconds faster than me. :-)